# Mozilla firefox columns fix

Tags: firefox, multiple-columns

I have problem with fixing columns in firefox. i'm trying to make 3 columns with 10px gap. it's working on google chrome and opera perfectly, but in firefox not.

There is an image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GM0L9.png

And the css code:

```
div#columns {
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-webkit-column-fill: auto;
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-fill: auto;
-ms-column-count: 3;
-ms-column-gap: 10px;
-ms-column-fill: auto;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 10px;
column-fill: auto;}

div.pin_shop {
display: inline-block;
background: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.11);
margin: 0 25px 25px 0;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
padding: 8px;}
```

Comment: can you show the markup

Comment: i found the solution. column-fill is not nesessary and now it's working. 

`column-count: 3;
 column-gap: 10px;
 -moz-column-count: 3;
 -moz-column-gap: 10px;
 -webkit-column-count: 3;
 -webkit-column-gap: 10px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**column-fill** is not necessary and now it's working.

```
column-count: 3; 
column-gap: 10px; 
-moz-column-count: 3; 
-moz-column-gap: 10px; 
-webkit-column-count: 3; 
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
```